# Material ui wrapper - reuse typescript types for a given prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

First of all sorry if this was answered before, I couldn't find it.

For some reasons in the app I am working right now we have a wrapper for some material-ui components. For instance I have a MyCompanyButton which is a wrapper for the material-ui Button component.

It is really simple, something like this:

```
const MyCompanyButton: React.FC<MyCompanyButtonProps> = (props): React.ReactElement => {
  const { label, color, type } = props;

  return (
    <Button color={color} type={type}>
      {label}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

The problem is with the types for the props.

My first attempt was to define them as this:

```
type MyCompanyButtonProps = {
  label: string;
  color: string;
  type: string;
};
```

But when I try to use my component like this:

```
<MyCompanyButton color="primary" type="submit" label="Send" />
```

I get the following error:

**Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"default" | "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined'.  TS2769**

I understand the error but I do not know how to fix it. I want to reuse material-ui types, but I can't find them. I know in current versions they are built-in in the core package, but I do not understand how to find the "color" type and apply it to my color prop.

What I did so far was take the type definition from the error and apply it to my prop:

color: "default" | "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined;

However, I think this is not the way to do it because if the type changes in the library I need to change it here too.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're doing this to extend the `Button` component as `label` is not part of the MUI Button props, you can extend your `MyCompanyButtonProps` type definition with the MUI ButtonProps type like this:

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';

interface MyCompanyButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  label: string;
}

export const MyCompanyButton: React.FC<MyCompanyButtonProps> = (props): React.ReactElement => {
  const { label, color, type } = props;

  return (
    <Button color={color} type={type}>
      {label}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

In general with the Material UI library, the component props can be imported from the same place as the component, with `Props` following the component name.